# Why do I need to call 'self' in this case?

Tags: python, oop, self

I am new to OOP and I am wondering why I need to supply the parameter MainWindow to the final line. If I call outside_func by itself, I don't need a parameter, but when I call it within a class i need to supply the class name for it to work. For example, MainWindow.class_func2() throws an error

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        print("in init")

    def claas_func(self):
        print ("func1")

    def class_func2(self):
        outside_func()

def outside_func():
    print('outside called')


instance = MainWindow()
MainWindow.class_func2(MainWindow)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. You have created an instance of MainWindow(). Now you can access its members with that.

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        print("in init")

    def claas_func(self):
        print ("func1")

    def class_func2(self):
        outside_func()

def outside_func():
    print('outside called')


instance = MainWindow()
instance.class_func2()
```

Also run this and notice it initializes the MainWindow() class 2x. I DO NOT recommend this second approach. It is redundant and not proper. But just so you can kind of see what it is doing.

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        print("in init")

    def claas_func(self):
        print ("func1")

    def class_func2(self):
        outside_func()

def outside_func():
    print('outside called')


instance = MainWindow()
MainWindow().class_func2()
```

Comment: Hmm that also works, why is that? Because the instance has a "self" parameter? I guess the idea of self is tripping me up a little

Comment: Note the difference between `MainWindow.class_func2()` and `instance.class_func2()`

Comment: What is the difference though?

Comment: Well, the first one is being called on the class (which is why it needs to know what instance you're trying to use) and the second is calling on the instance directly (so it knows how to populate the self parameter)

Comment: @Shadow is right, you need to utilize an instance of the class. Not just the reference the class.

Comment: @nickm So the answer to your original question "Why do I need to call 'self' in this case?" is you do not. You have an instance of the class and you can directly call its members. As for the self tripping you up, there are countless articles on self in python. I would just recommend reading a few until one of them clicks. It can be a hard concept to grab early on in OOP.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look to `@staticmethod`

```
class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        print("in init")

    def claas_func(self):
       print ("func1")

    @staticmethod
    def class_func2():
        return outside_func()

def outside_func():
    print('outside called')

instance = MainWindow()
>> in init

instance.class_func2()
>> outside called
```

this @staticmethod (which itself it's something really cool called 'decorator') will make the method itself entirely callable without having pass 'self'.

Hope it helps